# Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?' error Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

So I know many people have asked a similar question like this before but I'm still not able to get this working after following those solutions. I'm trying to generate a random color car from two arrays and store that in a dictionary. My code is below:

```
var colorTypeDictionary = [String:String]()
var colorArray = ["Red", "Black", "Silver", "Yellow", "Orange", "Blue", "Purple", "Pink", "White", "Gray", "Green"]
var carTypeArray = ["Ferarri", "Lamborghini", "Porsche", "Aston Martin", "Maserati"]
colorTypeDictionary[colorArray.randomElement()!] = [carTypeArray.randomElement()!]
print(colorTypeDictionary)
```

I keep getting the error around 
`[carTypeArray.randomElement()!]`. It says: Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String?'.

I've tried casting that line as a String but can't get it to work. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the square brackets:

```
colorTypeDictionary[colorArray.randomElement()!] = carTypeArray.randomElement()!
```

Answer (score 1):

`[carTypeArray.randomElement()!]` is of type `[String]` that you can't assign to dictionary value of type `String` , so Replace

```
colorTypeDictionary[colorArray.randomElement()!] = [carTypeArray.randomElement()!]
```

with

```
colorTypeDictionary[colorArray.randomElement()!] = carTypeArray.randomElement()!
```